# How to use custom model function in eco template with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

**Models**

```
Network.Models.FeedItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
  isPost: function() {
    return this.get('template') === 'post';
  }
})

Network.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/p',

  hasImageInDetails: function() {
    if(this.get('details').match(/<img[^<]*>[\w\d]*<\/img>|<img[^\/]*\/>/i)) {
      return true
    }
  }
)}
```

**Template**
`feed_items/post.jst.eco`

```
  <% if @model.hasImageInDetails(): %>
    has image
  <% end %>
```

**Views**

```
Network.Views.FeedItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.template = JST[this.path()];
  },

  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    $(this.el).html(this.template({ model: this.model }));

    if (this.model.isPost()) {
      this.questionView = new Network.Views.FeedItems.Post({
        model: this.model,
        el: this.$el,
        parent: this
      });
    }
  }
});

Network.Views.FeedItems.Post = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var self = this;
  }
});
```

But I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hasImageInDetails'
```

Comment: Can you also include the code for the method that calls `eco.render`? It looks like the `@model` variable in the template might not be a Backbone Model instance.

Comment: sure I included Post View

Comment: I don't see the template being rendered anywhere in that sample. Is it maybe called in the `TagsRoot` view?

Comment: Err.. it's still not there. You'd need to show the line of code where `eco.render(template, {model:...})` is called. Anyway, the issue is most likely that you're not passing the model correctly to the template.

Comment: Oh, sorry I found where it is.

Comment: hmm, but other things like ``@model.get('someAttr')`` works

Comment: yup, I think I got it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like from your code that you expect the `FeedItemView` to handle models of type `FeedItem`, because you call a method `model.isPost()`, which is defined on the `FeedItem`. The method Eco can't find is defined on the `Post` model, so logically, one of these will fail.

Did you mean to extend `Post` from `FeedItem`? In that case, instead of:

```
Network.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });
```

You should declare the model so:

```
Network.Models.Post = Network.Models.FeedItem.extend({ ... });
```

Comment: Ok, I changed model declaration as you write above and have defined that ``hasImageInDetails`` method in Post model but still have the same error in post.jst.eco template

Comment: Are you also passing `FeedItem`s into the `FeedItemView`? Your code would suggest so. Any model which doesn't have that method defined (or inherited) will cause that exception when passed into the `FeedItemView`, because it doesn't have the method to call. I think that's the issue. Your template looks fine otherwise. Good luck!